# notify me when data inserted in database php

Tags: javascript, php, database

```
if (($address == "") AND ( $date == "")) {
  echo "";
} else {
  date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
  $sent_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $sql = "INSERT INTO info (address,date) VALUES (:phone,:date)";
  $q = $CNT->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(
    array(
      ':address' => "$address",
      ':date' => "$sent_dt"
    )
  );
}
```

I want to put this script inside else so that every time there is a new data inserted it will notify me.

```
echo'<script>
    Push.create("Hello from the other side!", {
    body: "You're invited",
    icon: "img/k.jpg",
    timeout: 4000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.focus();
        this.close();
    }
  });
</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the statement execute returns true or false:

```
if($q->execute(array(':address'=>"$address",':date'=>"$sent_dt"))==TRUE) {
       echo ' <script>Push.create("Hello from the other side!", { body: "You\'re invited", icon: "img/k.jpg", timeout: 4000, onClick: function () { window.focus(); this.close(); }`` });</script> '; 
  }
```

Oh by the way we have to escape characters...