# can someone help me for the correct structure of this code because echo"inserted" wont show pl PHP

Tags: php, database

```
if (($email == "") AND ($message == "")) {
    echo "";
} else {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
    $sent_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO inbox (email,message,date) VALUES (:email,:message,:date)";
    $q = $CNT->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    if($q->execute(array(':email'=>"$email", ':message'=>"$message",':date'=>"$sent_dt")))
    {
        echo "inserted";
    }
}
```

Please help me with this problem, `echo "inserted"` won't show, that is why I can't receive any message that the data is received.

Comment: `$q>execute`? Really?

Comment: @tetsuyakuroko, please remove `phpmyadmin` . You made a typo, it should be `$q->execute`.

Comment: i already corrected my typo but still echo"inserted" wont show when new data inserted, by the way thank you guys <3

Comment: As far I remember, this question was asked 4 Hours before by different user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861334/notify-me-when-data-inserted-in-database-php

Comment: i think its my friend cause we still cannot debug it we need some advice and help that's why, btw thank you

Comment: @NanaPartykar can you help me? please thank you brother

Comment: What is happening right now? And, what you want? Elaborate more, please.

Comment: it only adds the data in the database but the echo "inserted " wont show. we need to show that the data is inserted using echo"inserted" under the if else condition

Comment: what is this `$q->execute(  ` followed by `if($q->execute(array....`? You need to show exact code. right now you hava a syntax error.

Comment: and you don't need the `==TRUE`. just remove this.

Comment: my ultimate goal is to notify using echo that insert is successfully done using the code above, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notify me when data inserted in database php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861334/notify-me-when-data-inserted-in-database-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `echo mysql_error();` for debugging after mysql execute. Also enable php debugging in php.ini or with command `display_errors(E_ALL);` at the beggining of script and send us response